# How to put default value in Responsive WYSIWYG Text Editor in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am using Responsive WYSIWYG Text Editor. I want to put the default value inside of its editor for updating data. When i inspect, I am getting the value like this:

```
<div id="txtEditor" style="display: none;">Test terms</div>
```

And the editor div turn into another div like:

```
<div class="Editor-editor" contenteditable="true" style="overflow: auto;"></div>
```

So how can i put my `<?php echo 'text'; ?>` inside `Editor-editor` div. Please help me to figure this thing out. I am not familiar with js. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
                var myEditor  = $("#txtEditor"); 
                myEditor.Editor();

// set initial  text in editor
                myEditor.Editor("setText", "text <?php echo time(); ?>");
// copy editor content to textarea
                myEditor.text(myEditor.Editor("getText"));

// copy editor content to textarea when keyup (is not recommended)
// fire only if you typing in editor not detect toolbars actions (eg. bolding)
 $(".Editor-editor").keyup(function(){
                myEditor.text(myEditor.Editor("getText"));
                });
// better is use same action when onsubmit form, or click in Save button

                });
```

Before you submit form you should copy text from editor to textarea

```
$('#txtEditor').text($('#txtEditor').Editor("getText"));
```

Comment: please let me now one more thing that how can i copy text from editor to textarea on keyup or keydown.

Comment: I changed my example. but it's definitely better to copy the content to textarea once before sending the form.